# reading multiple csv files in s3 and combined them as a single file when the name of files are different using R

Tags: r, amazon-s3

In each day I have multiple csv files with different names and I want to combine all CSVs in each day asa single file and put it in a loop for the other days as well.

```
   path= 's3://data/ y= 2017 /m= 05'
```

In m=05 I have multiple csv files (around 200) with different names and also in other days such as m=06 I have 120 csv files .

```
dates<- seq(as.Date('2017-05-05'), as.Date('2017-06-10'), "days")
for (i in 1:length(dates)){
dateofgen<-dates
filepath <- paste(path, "y=", format(as.Date(dateofgen), '%Y'), "/m=", format(as.Date(dateofgen), '%m'),"/d=",format(as.Date(dateofgen),'%d'), "/part-00012-e731138c-232c-48b0-958f-55f2c72f3327-c000.csv", sep='')
data <- s3read_using(read.csv, object=filepath, stringsAsFactors = F, bucket=gsub("/.*", '', gsub("s3://", '', filepath)))
}
```

How can I read and combine all files of a day into a single file using rbind or any merge function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use ***get_bucket_df*** method to get access to the object in the bucket and then using ***ldply function*** go through all objects in different days in each month and read s3 object using ***s3read_using()***.

```
days=as.character(c('17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'))
​
for (i in 01:31){
  path <- paste0("s3://data/ y= 2017 /m= 05/d=",days[i],sep = "")
  temp_df <- get_bucket_df(bucket = "data", prefix = path)
  temp_df <- temp_df[which(grepl(".csv", temp_df$Key)),]
  new_data <- ldply(temp_df$Key, function(x){
    s3path <- paste('s3://pa-datastore/',x,sep = "")
    raw_data <- s3read_using(read.csv, na.strings = '', header = FALSE, object = s3path, stringsAsFactors = F, bucket=gsub("/.*", '', gsub("s3://", '', s3path)))
    raw_data
  })
  dateofgen <- as.Date(paste0("2017-06-", days[i], sep = ""))
  new_path <- "s3://data/"
  filepath <- paste(new_path, "y=", format(as.Date(dateofgen), '%Y'), "/m=", format(as.Date(dateofgen), '%m'), "/newfile", dateofgen, ".csv", sep='')
  s3write_using(new_data, FUN=write.csv, row.names = F, object = filepath, bucket = gsub("/.*", '', gsub("s3://", '', filepath)))
base::print(paste0("completed for ", dateofgen, sep =""))
}
​
```